How to get the surface charge density of a metallic surface if it's potential is known?
For example, in the following question:

Two long coaxial cylindrical metallic shells of radii R1 and R2 are maintained at fixed potentials V1 and V2. The intervening medium is filled with a cloud of free charges at a uniform density of
ρvf C/m. Write down Poisson’s equation which governs the potential function and the boundary conditions. Hence, find V and E at different points far from ends.

What I reached was the boundary condition that states that D1-D2=ρsf, where D1 and D2 are the displacement vectors outside the cylinder and in the region where R1<s<R2 respectively, but I am stuck on getting the surface charge density at s=R2. Could it be zero, and if so, why?

I'm struggling with your notation. Is it D1 and D2 displacement operators? If yes, what would mean this $1$ and $2$ mean?
